# Enable offline 'NetFx3' feature in Windows 8.1 OS

Tags: msbuild, windows-installer

I am creating a installer with 'Windows 8.1' OS for my applications. I am using MSBUILD. By default 'Windows 8.1' OS contains .NET framework 4.5. But I need .NET framework 3.5 to run my applications.

First I install Windows OS using WinPE and then my applications on Windows - without user interfere.

I tried to enable 'NetFx3' feature (adding 'selection name="NetFx3" state="true"' in answer file) in windows image using Window SIM but as per [Microsoft website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443(v=vs.110).aspx) it needs internet connection. I tried and it fails.

After windows install if I run *DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:d:\sources\sxs* then it works fine on offline computer.

My other option is to run batch file with this command after windows install.

But I will prefer to install .NET framework through windows install. So my question is, how to make 'NetFx3' feature enabled in ISO itself (without internet connection), so that .NET framework 3.5 get installed during windows installation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and errors, I found the solution -

1. First I mounted iso file in Build\WindowsMount directory.
2. Remember to use latest dism 6.3.x from Windows 8.1 ADK.
3. An finally enable feature using this command *dism /image:Build\WindowsMount /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:Source\Windows\sxs*
4. And finally save image.

Answer (score 0):

Try followings

1. Add NET Framework 3.5 Features from "Windows Feature" in control panel[image]
2. Run following command in command prompt as Administrator
   `dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3
   /source:d:\sources\sxs`[image]

Then try re-installing the sql again. It works for me. Check [here](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/troubleshooting101.htm) more detail article